# Why does AMPL not recognize degrees[j] as integer when 'degrees' is a set of integers?

Tags: ampl

Or is there another problem?

It is my first time trying AMPL. I am trying to solve a nonlinear dynamic program. Here are parts of the first draft:

```
#defining degree
param degree >= 0 integer; # degree of polynomial approximation
param degrees {alpha in  0..degree}; # for storing degrees

...

# defining variables for optimization
var b {alpha in 0..degree}; # coefficient of polynomial

...

# defining constraints
subject to Upper_bound {i in M}: v[i] <= 
sum {k in 0..n} (comb[n,k]*(p^k)*((1-p)^(n-k))*((k/n)*((ch[k,i])^d)/(1-d)) +
((n-k)/n)*(cl[k,i]^d)/(1-d)+(1/(1+r))*(sum {j in 0..degree} 
(b[j]*cos(degrees[j]*acos((2*Anew[i]-Amax)/(Amax)))))));
```

I get a syntax error when I pass the mod file:

```
model DP.mod;

DP.mod, line 41 (offset 1658):
    syntax error
context:   >>> (b[j]*cos(degrees[j]*acos((2*Anew[i]-Amax)/(Amax))))))) <<< ;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved, thanks! There was an extra ending bracket.